# How to extract vertex/community colors from FindCommunityPlot

Tags: graphs-and-networks, color, style

How can I extract the colors of the individual vertices/communities from a `community graph plot`?
E.g.

```
g = RandomGraph[{20, 40}];
CommunityGraphPlot[g]
```

[image: CommunityGraphPlot of a random graph]

I would like to plot each vertex number with its respective community-graph plot-color in another plot. 
So far, I was able to get a list of the vertices in the respective communities with `FindGraphCommunities[g]`. How can I continue from here?

**Solution based on Szabolcs answer:**

By employing

```
foundCommunities = FindGraphCommunities[g]
communityColors = GraphComputation`GraphInformationDump`$AutomaticColorList
Table[Thread[foundCommunities[[i]] -> communityColors[[i]]], {i, 1,Length@foundCommunities}]
```

I get

```
{1->Hue[0, 1, 0.8], 5->Hue[0, 1, 0.8], ...}, {10->Hue[0.14, 1, 0.9],...},...}
```

which I can use in a different plot.

Comment: Can you explain the use case (within the question itself)?  Do you need to use these colours in a legend?

Comment: I am wondering what you are using this function for.

Comment: I want to use the colors associated with the individual vertex numbers in a different plot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Edited based on @halmir's comment.*

You can specify the colours manually by wrapping the community specifications in `Style[..., colour]`.

For example,

```
g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}]

communities = FindGraphCommunities[g]
(* {{4, 6, 7, 8, 10}, {1, 2, 9}, {3, 5}} *)

CommunityGraphPlot[g, 
 MapThread[Style, {communities, ColorData[81] /@ Range@Length[communities]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let us also evaluate the `MapThread[...]` separately to see what the community specification should look like.

```
MapThread[Style, {communities, 
  ColorData[81] /@ Range@Length[communities]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or in `InputForm`:

```
{Style[{4, 6, 7, 8, 10}, Hue[0.58, 1, 0.5]], 
 Style[{1, 2, 9}, Hue[0.12, 1, 0.9]], 
 Style[{3, 5}, Hue[0, 1, 0.75]]}
```

---

Where do the default colours come from?

`CommunityGraphPlot` uses `HighlightGraph` under the hood to highlight the vertices.  `HighlightGraph` uses the following internal colour function:

```
GraphComputation`GraphInformation["DefaultGroupColorFunction"]
```

This colour function takes the colours periodically from the following list:

```
GraphComputation`GraphInformationDump`$AutomaticColorList
```

For reference, in version 11.1.1 that is

```
{Hue[0, 1, 0.8], Hue[0.14, 1, 0.9], Hue[0.8, 0.6, 0.8], Hue[0.07, 1, 1], 
 Hue[0.2, 1, 0.6], Hue[0.1, 0.6, 0.7], Hue[0.5, 1, 0.7]}
```

---

If you want to re-use the colours in another place (for example add a legend), the cleanest solution is to specify the colours manually, as in the first example I showed.

Comment: you could specify color of community by wrapping groups with Style: CommunityGraphPlot[g, {Style[{4, 5, 7, 1, 2}, Green],Style[ {3, 6, 9, 8},Red]}]

Comment: @halmir Thank you.